# How to change gitosis default search path?

Tags: git, gitosis

I installed gitosis on my ubuntu desktop. But when I try "git clone git@localhost:gitosis-admin.git", it kept searching /home/git/, not /home/git/repositories. So I have to type "git clone git@localhost:repositories/gitosis-admin.git".

I guess there's something wrong with the default search path of gitosis. However, how to change it?

UPDATE 1:

I searched around and some pages says the reason of cannot clone use the address like "git@localhost:gitosis-admin.git" is because I'm on the git server itself. This still need time to validate.

UPDATE 2:

Even in another computer, still cannot use the shortest url. I gave it up.

UPDATE 3:

Now I turn to gitolite, and it's easier configure.

Comment: Yeah I *really* wish that it was published somewhere prominent that Gitosis is abandoned and people need to use Gitolite instead.

Comment: @Dan Ray After days of trying, I'd say Gitolite is much better. But there're too many tutorials on Gitosis, misleading people to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replay the part:

```
cd gitosis
sudo python setup.py install
```

The `setup.py` install script is supposed to create the repositories directory.
It takes the path from [util.py](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis/blob/master/gitosis/util.py):

```
def getRepositoryDir(config):
    repositories = os.path.expanduser('~')
    try:
        path = config.get('gitosis', 'repositories')
    except (NoSectionError, NoOptionError):
        repositories = os.path.join(repositories, 'repositories')
    else:
        repositories = os.path.join(repositories, path)
    return repositories
```

---

Note: considering the 'obsolete' status of the gitosis project, I mentioned in the comment **[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**.
The [OP liuyanghejerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/802650/liuyanghejerry) approved:

> You're right, I just installed gitolite in only few steps.
>   Now I can use `git clone gitolite:gitolite-admin.git`

Comment: I changed `repositories = os.path.expanduser('~')` to `repositories = os.path.expanduser('/home/git/repositories')` and rerun the script, but the problem is still there. But thanks.

Comment: @liuyanghejerry: since you have accepted my answer, how did you manage to make it work?

Comment: I've gave it up. I searched around, no one solved it in fact.

Comment: @liuyanghejerry: ok, consider then gitolite: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite. Much easier to configure, and quite up-to-date. Gitosis is now obsolete.

Comment: You're right, I just installed gitolite in only few steps. Now I can use `git clone gitolite:gitolite-admin.git`, but cannot use `git clone git@serverip:gitolite-admin.git`. Is that normal?

Comment: It's okay now. I googled around, and this is because that two grammar used two individual rsa keys. Really thanks, thanks for your time sharing for all of these.

Answer (score 1):

Change the home path of the `gitosis` user, eg:

```
sudo usermod --home /repos/gitosis --move-home
```

This should change the `gitosis` repository search path.

Comment: Sure, but gitosis is *really* obsolete. You should consider Gitolite.

Comment: Thanks, I've turn to gitolite, though.