# Git, Gitosis and multiple projects for one group

Tags: git, repository

My `gitosis.conf` reads:

```
[gitosis]

[group gitosis-admin]
members = myName@myComputer
writable = gitosis-admin

[group Project]
members = myName@myComputer
writable = ProjectOne ProjectTwo
```

However I can only successfully clone ProjectOne into a local directory. When I try to clone ProjectTwo similarly I get a timeout. Why is that?

I encounter the same problem if I try:

```
[gitosis]

[group gitosis-admin]
members = myName@myComputer
writable = gitosis-admin

[group ProjectOne]
members = myName@myComputer
writable = ProjectOne 

[group ProjectTwo]
members = myName@myComputer
writable = ProjectTwo
```

PS - I followed this reference https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git to set up Git on my remote server. It's working for one project only; I'd like to host multiple projects.

Comment: Gitosis? It is obsolete. Please use Gitolite. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591958/how-to-change-gitosis-default-search-path/7592421#7592421

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't concern myself too much with whether gitosis is obsolete or not, it's simple and just works. Really that's all one can ask for.

Here's how you'd do multiple projects per group, in my case I want a set of read-only members for my projects:

```
[group ReadOnlyClients]
readonly =  Project1 \
            Project2 \
            Project3 \
members  =  user1 user2 user3 user4
```

AFIAK you don't have to separate the projects on different lines, you can also just list them with a space between each much like the `members` setting

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't resolve issues I had with gitosis, moving to gitolite as VonC suggested in a comment works fine for me.